# Form Dropdown Not Registering in Codeigniter

Tags: database, codeigniter, validation

I have created a registration form that has a dropdown field, but I am unable to get it to link into the database to register the selection. I have form validation turned on, but it keeps saying that no value has been selected.

My other inputs work, as they're user entered. However, the values in this dropdown do not register as any value. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks!

**View**

```
<div class = "form-group">

 <?php echo form_label('Mobile Carrier'); ?><br/><!--Form Label-->

 <?php

    $data = array(

     'None'          => 'None',
     'att'          => 'AT&T',
     'verizon'      => 'Verizon',
     'sprint'       => 'Sprint',
     'tmobile'      => 'T-Mobile'
     );
 ?>
 <?php echo form_dropdown('Mobile Carrier', $data, 'None'); ?>
```

**Controller**

```
public function register(){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile_carrier', 'Mobile Carrier', 'required'); }
```

**User Model**

```
public function create_user(){

    $data = array(

        'first_name'        => $this->input->post('first_name'),
        'last_name'         => $this->input->post('last_name'),
        'email'             => $this->input->post('email'),
        'phone_number'      => $this->input->post('phone_number'),
        'mobile_carrier'    => $this->input->post('mobile_carrier'),
        'username'          => $this->input->post('username'),
        'password'          => $encrypted_pass
    );
    $insert_data = $this->db->insert('users', $data);
    return $insert_data;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are assigning the wrong `name` attribute when creating the dropdown list:

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('Mobile Carrier', $data, 'None'); ?>
```

the `name` attribute must match your `$this->input->post('mobile_carrier')` in your model. so the correct use would be:

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('mobile_carrier', $data, 'None'); ?>
```

more information: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html, scroll to `form_dropdown([$name = ''[, $options = array()[, $selected = array()[, $extra = '']]]])`